# Reverse row "order" value from table MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with rows and each one has an "order" value. Now, I have like 500 rows and I need to reverse the "order" values. So the first one should be last and so on.

For example:

```
Name   |  Order
-------------------
Row 1  |    1
Row 2  |    4
Row 3  |    5
Row 4  |    8
Row 5  |    12
Row 6  |    20
```

Should now be:

```
Name   |  Order
-------------------
Row 1  |    20
Row 2  |    12
Row 3  |    8
Row 4  |    5
Row 5  |    4
Row 6  |    1
```

I need to do this just one time so performance doesn't really matter. How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: Is the data already in the wrong order, and you just want to reverse it? Use the "sort()" or "rsort()" function, depending on ascending or descending order.

If the data is in some random order, and you just want to reverse that order but still maintain the original randomness, you have to do something else.

Comment: The data is in the wrong order and I want to reverse it and store it reversed in the database.

Comment: Is their any reson ORDER BY Order DESC  in the sql would not work?

Comment: *"The data is in the wrong order and I want to reverse it and store it reversed in the database"* SQL tables are **orderless** by SQL definition so do not bother changing it.. You should be using `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Order DESC` like @JasonK already mentioned

Comment: @JasonK when I create a row, I check for the highest order from the database and add one, and insert the row with that order. But I wasn't using DESC so now all rows are reversed (the latest rows are at the bottom). That's why I need to only do it once. I don't know if I'm explaining myself here

Comment: Just negate the values.

Comment: *"I don't know if I'm explaining myself here "* You do but the SQL standard does not have `INSERT INTO ... POSITION FIRST` @nick for a good reason.

Comment: If you'd like to do this entirely with a query, I would assume you could leverage [row_number](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) in an update statement.

Comment: OP wants to adjust the values so that 1 becomes 20 and 20 becomes 1. What exactly does this have to do with ORDER BY?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you're a genius, never could've think of that

Comment: @SalmanA everything more or less.. After the `UPDATE` change which Paul suggested a simple `SELECT * FROM table` also might mess up the order, without `ORDER BY` the resultset is non deterministic (random) by SQL definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only requirement is

> So the first one should be last and so on

you can just negate the values (as I wrote in the comments). That can be done with

```
update mytable set `Order` = - `Order`
```

However - Here is an SQL script which will "swap" the values in the `Order` column from least to greatest, from second least to second greatest ond so on..

```
create table tmp_asc(
  i int auto_increment primary key,
  o int,
  index (o)
);

insert into tmp_asc(o)
  select `Order` from mytable order by `Order` asc;

create table tmp_desc(
  i int auto_increment primary key,
  o int,
  index (o)
);

insert into tmp_desc(o)
  select `Order` from mytable order by `Order` desc;

update mytable t
join tmp_asc on tmp_asc.o = t.Order
join tmp_desc on tmp_desc.i = tmp_asc.i
set t.Order = tmp_desc.o;

drop table tmp_asc, tmp_desc;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/roA9PeqUe35AwqVK5yzjWc/0)

MySQL 8 with window functions makes it simpler:

```
with cte as (
  select `Order`
  , row_number() over (order by `Order` asc)  as rn_asc
  , row_number() over (order by `Order` desc) as rn_desc
  from mytable
)
update mytable t
join cte a on a.Order = t.Order
join cte d on d.rn_desc = a.rn_asc
set t.Order = d.Order;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x8bszndykcnt5Crktusbfj/0)

Comment: Thanks, I just negated the values since it was the easiest option but I appreciate the other options as well!

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP "rsort()" function. It will sort the array from largest value to smallest.

Then save that to your database.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php